# In Go, even though []byte is passed to a method by value, the original value is still modified?

Tags: go

Normally, the original value will change only if it's passed as a pointer to a method.
But I see this scenario that the original value is changed when it's passed as a value to a method. This happens a lot in implementations of Reader interface.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("Hello, Reader!")

    b := make([]byte, 8)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(b)
        fmt.Printf("n = %v err = %v b = %v\n", n, err, b)
        fmt.Printf("b[:n] = %q\n", b[:n])
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

the variable `b` is passed to the Read method using value

```golang
n, err := r.Read(b)
```

but somehow the original value got changed and populated with data to print with.

If I look into the implementation of Read method

```golang
func (r *Reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if r.i >= int64(len(r.s)) {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    r.prevRune = -1
    n = copy(b, r.s[r.i:])
    r.i += int64(n)
    return
}
```

We can clearly see it's a value parameter?
This obeys how in go everything is passed and copied by value.

From my understand, `b` should at least be passed as a pointer like

```golang
func (r *Reader) Read(b *[]byte) (n int, err error) {
```

Why is this? Please help thanks.

Comment: Read https://blog.golang.org/slices and take the Tour of Go once more which explains what slices are and how they behave.

Comment: Yes, thank you I forgot about the actual implementation of slice. thanks

Answer (score 2):

> A slice does not directly hold its contents. Instead a slice holds a pointer to its underlying array which holds the contents of the slice.

So, essentially yes, you are passing by value, but the value is a pointer the "backing array".

See: https://dave.cheney.net/2018/07/12/slices-from-the-ground-up